# React contentEditable and cursor position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple component

```
class ContentEditable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    let html = event.target.innerHTML;
    if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {
      this.props.onChange({ target: { value: html, name: this.props.name } });
      this.lastHtml = html;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span
        contentEditable="true"
        onInput={this.handleInput}
        className={"auto " + this.props.className}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.value }}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default ContentEditable;

<ContentEditable
  value={this.state.name}
  onChange={e => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  }}
/>;
```

The component works but the cursor position never changes, it is always  on first position instead after the rendered text.

I tested examples form this forum but it doesn't work for me.

I use `React 15.6.1` and test it on `chrome (Os X)`.

Any hint how I can solve this problem?

Comment: related: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2047. most likely you need to make the component uncontrolled and use a `ref`.

Comment: thanks, great it works

Comment: If you're planning on making use of `contentEditable` in your React application, consider using [Draft.js](https://draftjs.org/). It's a lot less painful to work with in a lot of cases.

Comment: @JoeClay yes I know to edit bigger text I use Draft.js but this is only to edit little parts of data. But important is auto resize to the content and this is reason why span is better than input/textarea

Comment: Would someone mind posting the solution from Davin's comment as answer?

Comment: throwing this out there not sure if it's OP's problem, for me the newly typed letter was prepended to what was typed, I just called reverse on the e.target.innerText value before setting state. This is using onInput

Answer (score 15):

The solution with `useRef` will be something look like below.

```
const ContentEditableWithRef = (props) => {
  const defaultValue = useRef(props.value);

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    if (props.onChange) {
      props.onChange(event.target.innerHTML);
    }
  };

  return (
    <span
      contentEditable
      onInput={handleInput}
      className="custom-textarea"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: defaultValue.current }}
    />
  );
};
```

Full codesandbox is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-microservice-efouz?file=/src/App.js:456-849), use this to see how this works!

> The code sandbox example contains two components
>
> - one is `ContentEditableWithRef` which solves the problem with `useRef` , which is an uncontrolled component and
> - the other component is `ContentEditable` which uses `useState` to solve the same problem.

Here the `useRef` will keep the default value / initial value apart from the component rendering cycles, so it will retain the original value without being affected by other kinds of operations we do in the react component.

This component does two things

1. This will emit the user input to the parent component with an `onChange` method
2. Takes a default value from parent component as `prop` named `value` and renders the value in the custom input box (that was created using `contentEditable`)

Comment: Can you explain how ref-based/state-based solution preserves cursor position?

Comment: Ref based will not rerender the component so the cursor will remain

Comment: import React, {  useRef } from "react";
export default function ContentEditor(props) {
    //const  = useRef < HTMLDivElement > (null);
  const defaultValue=useRef(props.value);
  const handleInput=(event)=>{
    if(props.onChange){
        props.onChange(event.target.innerHtml);
    }
  }
  return (
    <span
    contentEditable={true}
    onInput={handleInput}
    className="custom-textarea"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:defaultValue.current}}

    />
  );
}

Comment: For the next genreation, I added above the code as text and not as image as it is written in the answers (great answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. You just saved me a lot of time. I was having a problem with the duplication of the content when finishing editing, but using the dangerouslySetInnerHTML function solved the issue, even with the straight state value with no need to use useRef

Comment: For those worried with security and the danger warning on the name of the function, there's a library called 'dompurify' which has the 'sanitize' function that can be used to clear HTML content from whatever threat it may contain.

Answer (score 2):

I also had same problem. Just fixed it with `ref`.  Just assign `textContent` of event.target to `ref`.

```
const textareaEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    textareaEl.current.textContent = e.target.textContent;
    onChange(e); // If you have change event for form/state
};

/** If you're passing value from state, 
    you can mutate it each change for not losing cursor position. 
 */
useEffect(() => {
  if (value) {
     textareaEl.current.textContent = value;
  }
}, [value]);


return (
    <div
      id="textarea-element"
      ref={textareaEl}
      contentEditable={true}
      suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
      onChange={handleChange}
     />
)
```

Comment: onChange doesn't get called but onInput get called

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and needed to set the value within the component without losing the cursor, so I tried @Lakshmaji solution and it worked. However, I had the need to update that input value also from its parent, and that solution didn't let that (the value didn't update).

So I tried @rufatZZ solution and it worked for my second problem (updating the value from the parent), but didn't solve the lost cursor position issue.

So I did a mix from both solutions, mainly the @rufatZZ solution but using the value reference with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as proposed by @Lakshmaji and it worked for me.

Here:

```
// this was from @Lakshmaji and keeps me the cursor position
const defaultValue = useRef(value);

// this was from @rufatZZ and allows me to keep the value even with updates from the parent
const textAreaElement = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

/** If you're passing value from state, 
    you can mutate it each change for not losing cursor position. 
 */
useEffect(() => {
  if (value && textAreaElement.current) {
    textAreaElement.current.textContent = value;
  }
}, [value]);


function handleInputChange(event) {
  if (textAreaElement.current) {
    textAreaElement.current.textContent = event.currentTarget.innerText;
  }

  // propagate the changed value to the parent
  onChange?.(event.currentTarget.innerText);
}

return (
  <span
    contentEditable
    ref={textAreaElement}
    suppressContentEditableWarning
    onInput={handleInputChange}
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: defaultValue.current }}
  />
);
```