# Dynamically highlight characters after certain length?

Tags: reactjs, textarea, counter, highlight, use-state

I have the following basic React app using the `useState` hook, which creates a text box and counts the characters users input:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App(){

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0); 


  return (
    <div>
      <textarea 
        placeholder="What's happening?" 
        onChange={e => setCount(e.target.value.length)}
      />
      <p>You typed {count} characters</p>
    </div>
  )

}

export default App;
```

Here is the result, without any styling:
[image]

My problem now is I would like to highlight characters if the input characters count is greater than 30. As the user types, if the input text exceeds 30 characters, the next characters will be highlighted. If `count` becomes 31, that one extra character should be highlighted red (or some other color).

I am lost how to achieve this with textarea (and using React).

How would users accomplish this?

Comment: let me try a thing here.

Comment: Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, this is something I did in 10 min, but it works and you can figure the rest out.

also  [codeSandBox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-waterfall-0yq5p?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [charLength, setCharLength] = useState(0);
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const inputEl = useRef(null);

  const maxLength = () => {
    inputEl.current.value = "for something like something something something";
    inputEl.current.setSelectionRange(10, 999);
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>char length: {charLength}</h1>
      <h2>max length: 10</h2>
      <input
        ref={inputEl}
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setCharLength(e.target.value.length)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => maxLength()}>Focus the input</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I think this is a start, as after "for someth", the text becomes highlighted. I would like the highlighting to occur as the user dynamically types input into the textbox of course. I'll keep playing around, thanks!

Comment: You can use the function on onChange on the input, I can continue later tonight and fix that so after say 15 characters it will highlight it with red even if you keep typing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar requirement and I was struggling to find a proper solution in React. So, I created this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/content-editable-highlight-over-limit-5jhnx4?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A9%2C1) that is using an uncontrolled contentEditable div with a ref to update the innerHTML of the div without having the issue with the cursor jumping in the beginning as mentioned also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64658794/3797803

However, the challenging part had to do when the innerHTML of the div included the span with the highlighted text when the limit was exceeded. On that case, there was again an issue with the cursor jumping in the beginning of the text. In order to address that, I had to save the current cursor position before updating the innerHTML of the div and after that, restoring it.