# Adjusting elements in the React DOM based on render-time information (i.e. line height)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

### Context

I have created a simple text-editor with line-numbers using React JS. It should only edit plaintext (i.e. no rich text editing is desired). The text-input field is represented with a `contentEditable` div. When typing, I am facing three challenges:

1. I want line-numbers to appear for each newline.
2. I do not want to re-render to the DOM the user is typing in, because it will reset the cursor ([see a sort of similar question about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306325/react-contenteditable-and-cursor-position)).
3. I want line-numbers to only appear for actual newlines. Not for lines that wrap-around due to the boundary of the containing box.

---

### Attempted Solution

1. To show line-numbers, I create a column of numbers next to the editable content. I use React's `map` to create one for each line. ✅
2. To avoid the problem with the DOM re-rendering, I used `React.useRef` to ensure that my text input does not get re-rendered (and the cursor position is not lost). ✅
3. To ensure that line numbers only appear next to actual newlines, I tried to mirror the text-input in a hidden div. The idea is that I can insert each line into its own div. Then, I can get the height of the div of each line, and use it to set the height of the line-number divs so they are matching (see figure below) ❌ :

[image]

Unfortunately, this is presently not working quite how I wanted. I can't seem to figure out how to fetch the heights of the rendered div's, and then set them for the line-numbers. I've tried to use `useEffect` to run *after* the DOM is rendered, but I'm not able to find out how to 'hook' into the div-array and calculate their height.

---

## Minimum Code Example

Please see this [working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vy41t9sL/71/). Unfortunately I could't get it to work in the StackOverflow code tool. For convenience, I still paste the relevant code below:

#### React + JavaScript

```
const initialText=`Nature's first green is gold,
Her hardest hue to hold.
Her early leaf's a flower;
But only so an hour.
Then leaf subsides to leaf.
So Eden sank to grief,
So dawn does down to day.
Nothing gold can stay.`

function App () {
  const [lines, setLines] = React.useState(initialText.split("\n"));
  let text = React.useRef(initialText)
  
  React.useEffect(() => { 
    console.log('Rendered!')
    // TODO: Update the height of each line-number to match the real-lines
  });
  
  function handleInput(e) {
    console.log('Edited!')
    setLines(e.target.textContent.split("\n"));
  }
  
  return (
    <div  className='container'>
      <div className='margin'>
          {lines.map((line,i)=>(<div>{(1+i).toString()}</div>))}
      </div>

      <div className='editor-container'>
        <div onInput={handleInput} contentEditable='plaintext-only' className='editor' suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>
          {text.current}
        </div>
        <div className='editor' style={{visibility:'hidden'}}>
          {lines.map(line=>(<div>{line}</div>))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"))
root.render(<App/>)
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.margin {
  text-align: right;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 1em;
}

.margin > div {
  width: 100%;
}

.editor-container {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.editor {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy41t9sL/71/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the heights of the rendered divs you need to:

1. Get the contents of the hidden div through `ref`:

```js
<div ref={hiddenContentRef} className='editor' style={{visibility:'hidden'}}>
```

2. Iterate through each inner div using `useLayoutEffect` once `lines` is changed, get the height of each div(`item.getBoundingClientRect().height`) and store it into the state:

```js
  const [linesHeight, setLinesHeight] = React.useState(new Array(lines.length).fill(0));

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => { 
     // Update the height of each line number to match the real-lines
      hiddenContentRef.current.childNodes.forEach(function(item, index){
        setLinesHeight(prevLines => ([...prevLines.slice(0, index), item.getBoundingClientRect().height, ...prevLines.slice(index + 1)]))
    });
  }, [lines]);
```

Then you will be able to set an appropriate height for each line number:

```
<div className='margin'>
  {lines.map((line,i)=>(<div style={{height: `${linesHeight[i]}px`}}>{(1+i).toString()}</div>))}
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st3hkrvq/16/)

Comment: Thanks this helped! Leaving it up for a bit longer then will accept your answer :)